# Why is OAuth2WebServerFlow used in this example?

Tags: google-api-python-client

In its [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/access_from_python) describing how to build a command-line client to access an API published at an App Engine endpoint, `Oauth2WebServerFlow` is used to get the `flow` object to be used to obtain credentials. I wasn't able to figure out how to use this for a command-line application.

After spending hours trying to figure out why I was still getting 401 errors even after managing to obtain credentials using the published example, I located [a nice page](http://www.datadependence.com/2016/03/google-python-library-oauth2) containing the following working code:

```
flow = oauth2client.client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
        'client_secret.json',  # downloaded file
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'  # scope
        redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
```

Is the example published by Google actually incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are showing different methods to give authorization.

In the Google example, you must get your `client_id` and `client_secret` strings and assign them to the variables `CLIENT_ID`, and `CLIENT_SECRET`, respectively.  In the example, they are just empty strings.

The actual process of getting the authorization URL, getting the authorization, and storing the credentials is all done within `tools.run_flow`

In the blog, they are doing all of that in their own code.  They are also requiring the user to copy and paste the authorization code, which is done automatically in the Google example.

Are you getting any error messages or failures?

Edit: Also, `flow_from_clientsecrets` returns an `OAuth2WebServerFlow` object, but has additional error checking that is not in the Google example.

Comment: You're right. I tried it again, now that I have a little better idea what's going on, and Google's example works perfectly. It is indeed preferable as it doesn't require you to copy/paste the auth code from the browser.